# How to call sms api in ionic 4?

Tags: angular, api, ionic-framework, sms, ionic4

calling sms api using ionic 4

please tell me

Can anyone guide me how to call api in proper way, and how to pass the parameters in proper way.

Answer (score -1):

Hi keshav please go through following steps.

1. We will also need the Cordova plugin for reading the SMS and @ionic-native/sms Package

   `ionic cordova plugin add cordova-sms-plugin`
   `npm install @ionic-native/sms`
2. Then add sms module in module.ts file then import these package in your component

   `import { SMS } from '@ionic-native/sms/ngx';`
3. Declare in constructor

   `private sms: SMS`
4. Then just call the method

   `this.sms.send('416123456', 'Hello world!');`